# I have a list in the constant but when reflecting it in a list it gives me a white screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to transfer a list but the screen went blank

```
<ul className='flex flex-col gap-2 font-bodyFont'>
  {
    listItem.map(item => 
      item.listData.map(data => (
        <li>{data}</li>
      ))
    )
  }
</ul>
```

a way to pass the data cleanly and without the white screen

Comment: You may need to flatten the map.

Answer (score 0):

If there is blank screen, then there must be error message showing in the console. Meanwhile you can change this code like this

```
<ul className='flex flex-col gap-2 font-bodyFont'>
 {
   listItem?.map(item = >item?.listData?.map((data, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{data}</li>
   )))
 }
</ul>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using optional chaining. This will not through any error if listItem or listData is undefined or null

```
 <ul className='flex flex-col gap-2 font-bodyFont'>
  {
    listItem?.map(item => 
      item.listData?.map(data => (
        <li>{data}</li>
      ))
    )
  }
</ul>
```

You can read more about optional chaining here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining